# DOS network-adapter driver compatible with VirtualBox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, drivers, ms-dos

I'm migrating some DOS machines to VirtualBox. I use the common NetWare-style IPX stack. The problem is that VirtualBox doesn't emulate any of the network-adapters that I have drivers for. So, where do I find a driver for any of the network-adapters that VirtualBox can emulate?

Comment: Doesn’t VirtualBox have Guest Additions for DOS?

Comment: The folks over on [Retrocomputing SE](http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/) might have more hints. Though I added an answer here from my recent experience.

Comment: No, there are no Guest Additions for DOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this Question is too old to migrate to Retro SE...

I got PC-DOS 2000 to work on VirtualBox by loading PCNTPK.COM on startup (a DEVICE line in CONFIG.SYS) and then running DHCP from [mTCP](http://www.brutman.com/mTCP/) (I just invoked it from AUTOEXEC.BAT, which means you can run it anytime you like). I didn't mess with any NDIS or IPX stuff at all (at least deliberately).

Oh, you should set networking to Bridged Adapter. NAT only works in one direction for DOS guests, I recall.

Comment: Doesn't NAT in VirtualBox always just work in one direction for any guest? But I guess that is normally not a problem unless you run an ancient FTP client, but for DOS it might be a problem. But it doesn't matter for me since I'm using it for IPX and the VB NAT is only for TCP/IP. (Brigged Adapter works fine with IPX by the way.)

Comment: I suppose Bridged is recommended by Oracle for full host networking, including sharing file via local services (because there are no guest additions).

Answer (score 2):

Ben Armstrong, Virtualization Program Manager, [suggests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/virtual_pc_guy/setting-up-dos-ipx-networking-under-virtual-pc-2004)

downloading

- ftp://ftp.symantec.com/public/english_us_canada/products/ghost/layers/LSL.ZIP
- ftp://ftp.symantec.com/public/english_us_canada/products/ghost/layers/IPXODI.ZIP
- Novc_300.zip from http://developer.intel.com/design/network/drivers/novc_300.htm

then running

- LSL
- DC21X4
- IPXODI

in that order.

Comment: I cannot get it to work. The driver is for Intel 21x4 network-adapters. But VirtialBox (4.0.12) only supports Intel 8254 and PcNet 79c97x. I just get the message: "DC21X4-DOS-50: Board not found in system". Am I missing something?